# Putting multiple keywords in "if x in message.content discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a super simple discord.py bot and I wanted to put multiple keywords inside a single "if x in message.content"

```py
if ('among us' or 'impostor') in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Do I see an Among Us reference?')
```

[image]

I tried using the or logical operator but it just doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use the [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function.

```
if any(x in message.content for x in ["among us", "impostor"]):
       await message.channel.send('Do I see an Among Us reference?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a file that the function will read, so it is easier to add multiple words.

We need to import json.

```
import json
```

Then we need to open the file blacklist.json, or whatever your file is called.

```
with open("blacklist.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

We create the on message event.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.guild:
        return
    if message.author == self.client.user:
        return
    try:
        for word in data:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                await message.channel.send("That word is in my list!")
    except:
        pass
```

Now create a words.json file in your main directory and put words in it as followed.

```
[
  "word1",
  "word2"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate a list of words:

```py
words = ["among us", "impostor"]
for w in words:
  if w in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Do I see an Among Us reference?')
```